# Re-use same adapter for multiple almost similar fragments

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 of four `Fragment`s being almost the same. They display a `GridLayout` with images and text below each image. I have already finished the code for one of them. 
I use a `Retrofit` service to get the data from the server. Objects are the same except 1-2 fields that I only need them for the de-serialization.

Example of one of the Objects  :

```
public class TagsItem implements Serializable{

@SerializedName("post_id")
private String postId;

@SerializedName("account_id")
private int accountId;

private String tags;
private String description;
private String image;
private String name;

// removed getters/setters for brevity

}
```

I only need image and name from each class.

I'd like to use if it's possible the same adapter for each one of them since they don't need a separate layout for each item. It's just image and name.

How should I declare the Adapter in a more generic form so it would be usable be all 3 ?

Right now the code for the adapter is :

```
public class TagsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TagsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<TagsItem> dataset;

public TagsAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    dataset = new ArrayList<>();
}

// more adapter code

}
```

As you can see the name is `TagsAdapter` and the dataset type is `TagsItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to create a common interface for all of different objects. Since you say that all you need is the "image" and "name" properties, it would likely be something like this:

```
interface NamedImage {
 public String getImage();
 public String getName();
}
```

Each of your classes to be displayed by the adapter would then implement that interface.

Then you'd simply change your adapater to work with NamedImage instead of TagsItem